# write two values to csv row in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

So I have a solved problem, but I don't like the solution :)

```
with open(outfile, 'a') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file) #opens a csv writer
    #inserts ID to front of wordList
    wordList.insert(0,ID)
    writer.writerow(wordList)
    #removes ID
    wordList.remove(ID)
```

Right now it successfully writes an ID and a list of words into csv form (as far as I can tell-- I don't actually have excel on my computer). The part I don't like is that I have to insert and remove the ID, because I don't want it included later. This seems lame. Can I somehow do a double insert to the same row, easily?

I tried:

```
 writer.writerow([ID,wordList])
```

but it gave undesirable square brackets

This is for 2.7, if that matters!
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
writer.writerow([ID] + wordList)
```

or

```
from itertools import chain

writer.writerow(chain([ID], wordList))
```

Comment: I know in this situation these would function the same, but is there an advantage (performance or otherwise) that would make one better than the other for a larger scale? Thanks!

Comment: `itertools.chain` will concatenate an arbitrary number of sequences [_doc_](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Answer (score 1):

You could do `writer.writerow([ID] + wordList)`.

Comment: Python never lets me down, neither does Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follow:

```
writer.writerow([ID] + wordlist)
```

Comment: Great! I knew there was some python semantic wizardry that would do this